# Wrong diff while committing through egit

Tags: eclipse, github, egit

After committing from eclipse through Egit, diffs on GitHub showed all lines removed and added when there was no difference in them.

Comment: This can happen for a number of reasons.  One is that you have a line endings issue.  In that case, each line really is different between the two files.  No, Git is not broken.

Comment: I guess the diff is correct and there are invisible whitespace changes, probably if all lines are affected then the line endings have changed. In the Compare editor press Ctrl+3 and enter `Show Whitespace Characters` in the Quick Access field and press Enter to make these changes visible.